# starting nginx -g 'daemon off;' from a script does not stay in front

Tags: nginx

I am trying to start nginx from a script and want to see it running in foreground.

It is already running when I run the script. Therefore I am trying with the following:

```
nginx -s stop
sleep 5
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

The problem is that it still runs as a deamon - not in the foreground. And it ends the process?